# Building multiple lists from single list with multiple lists within

Tags: python

```
def main():

    my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open("Alpha.txt")]
    print(my_list)
    for elem in my_list:
        listA=[]
        listA = elem
        print(listA)


main()
```

this code prints out the correct data of which im looking for, however i need to set each print from the for loop into a object. Any help as to how i would go about doing that?

```
[1.2, 4.3, 7.0, 0.0]
[3.0, 5.0, 8.2, 9.0]
[4.0, 3.0, 8.0, 5.6]
[8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 7.4]
```

Comment: What kind of object?? a list is an object.

Comment: Do you want to put each list in a different variable?

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion, i want each line to become a different variable like a = [1.2, 4.3, 7.0, 0.0]
b = [3.0, 5.0, 8.2, 9.0]
and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're thinking of/trying to do is to dynamically name variables.

Don't.

Either leave your data in the `list` and access it via index

```
my_list[0] #what you were trying to assign to 'a'
my_list[0][0] #the first element in that sub-list
```

Or, if you have meaningful identifiers that you want to assign to each, you can use a `dict` to assign "keys" to "values".

```
d = {}
for sublist, meaningful_identifier in zip(my_list, my_meaningful_identifiers):
    d[meaningful_identifier] = sublist
```

Either way, leverage python data structures to do what they were supposed to do.

Comment: You may want to consider having your meaningful_identifiers contained within the input file and create a dict as roippi suggests

Comment: you are so correct, feel very dumb for not recognizing i could just use the my_list[]. question though, if the data in alpha.txt was changed with more or less data, how would i have a dynamic code to ensure all of the data is read correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a good idea, let me warn you, and you should never use this in production code (it is prone to code injection), and screws up your global namespace, but it does what you asked.**

You would use `exec()` for this, which is a function that dynamically executes statements.

```
def main():
    my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open("Alpha.txt", "r")]
    print(my_list)
    for elem in my_list:
        exec "%s = %s" % ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[my_list.index(elem)], elem) in globals()

main()
```

Now, your global namespace is filled with variables a, b, c, etc. corresponding to the elements.

It is also prone to exceptions, if you have more than 26 elements, you will get an IndexError, although you could work around that.

Comment: yeah the a, b, c , d are very stupid names i agree. in my final code i would set the to something much more meaningful and less confusing such as my_list_first my_list_second and such. Thanks for the breakdown of exec()!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myList = [map(float, line.split(',')) for line in open ("Alpha.txt")]
```

Now you can get each line in a different variable if you want:

```
a = myList[0]
b = myList[1]
```

and so on. But since you have a list, it's better to use it and access elements using indices. Are you sure have a correct understanding of arrays?

As the other answers point out, it is dangerous and doesn't make sense to dynamically create variables.

Comment: i havent yet learned about arrays fully, but your code makes complete sense.